# Typescript and Firebase 9

Tags: typescript, firebase

I have been upgrading from Firebase 8 to Firebase 9 (modular web version) and have run into problems with Typescript compiler problems. The upgrade process is described here:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/modular-upgrade

Previously Firebase was imported and initialised thus:

```
import app from 'firebase/app';

const firebaseApp: firebase.app.App = firebase.initializeApp(options);
```

In Firebase 9, the recommended approach is to

```
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app"

const firebaseApp = initializeApp({ /* config */ });
```

I want to give the const firebaseApp a typing as I did before. How do i do this?

I have also got lots of weird typing errors generated by the Typescript compiler that didn't happen with Firebase 8.

node_modules/@firebase/auth/dist/auth-exp-public.d.ts:1097:47 - error TS2748: Cannot access ambient const enums when the '--isolatedModules' flag is provided.

1097     static readonly FACEBOOK_SIGN_IN_METHOD = SignInMethod.FACEBOOK;
~~~~~~~~~~~~
How do I get rid of these? I deleted node_modules/@firebase and reinstalled firebase 9 but it made no difference.

Answer (score 2):

For the FACEBOOK_SIGN_IN_METHOD error, I think you need to attach some code to here for us to debug. Firebsae has a huge change of how to require feature e.g. `getAuth()` instead of `firebaseApp.auth`

**// v9**

```
import { initializeApp, FirebaseApp } from "firebase/app"
import { getAuth } from "firebase/auth";

const firebaseApp: FirebaseApp = initializeApp({ /* config */ });
const auth = getAuth(firebaseApp)
```

**// v8**

```
import firebase from 'firebase/app';

const firebaseApp: firebase.app.App = firebase.initializeApp({});
firebaseApp.auth
```

Comment: I have converted my app in line with documentation but these Typescript compilation errors (TS2748) just appear. If I set the isolatedModules flag to false, the errors stop. Looks like an error in the typings?

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else who ends up  here, I believe it should be..

```
import { environment } from '../environments/environment';
import { initializeApp, provideFirebaseApp, getApp } from '@angular/fire/app';
import { provideAuth, getAuth, connectAuthEmulator } from '@angular/fire/auth';
import { provideFirestore, getFirestore, connectFirestoreEmulator } from '@angular/fire/firestore';
import { provideFunctions, getFunctions, connectFunctionsEmulator } from '@angular/fire/functions';
import { provideStorage, getStorage, connectStorageEmulator } from '@angular/fire/storage';

imports: [
    ...
    provideFirebaseApp(() => initializeApp(environment.firebase)),
    provideAuth(() => {
      const auth = getAuth();
      if (location.hostname === 'localhost') {
        connectAuthEmulator(auth, 'http://127.0.0.1:9099', { disableWarnings: true });
      }
      return auth;
    }),
    provideFirestore(() => {
      const firestore = getFirestore();
      if (location.hostname === 'localhost') {
        connectFirestoreEmulator(firestore, '127.0.0.1', 8080);
      }
      return firestore;
    }),
    provideFunctions(() => {
      const functions = getFunctions();
      if (location.hostname === 'localhost') {
        connectFunctionsEmulator(functions, '127.0.0.1', 5001);
      }
      return functions;
    }),
    provideStorage(() => {
      const storage = getStorage();
      if (location.hostname === 'localhost') {
        connectStorageEmulator(storage, '127.0.0.1', 5001);
      }
      return storage;
    }),
  ],
```